# How to Calculate Exponential Moving Average (EMA) of last 200 days in Google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to calculate the Exponential Moving Average (EMA) of stock. I found this formula:

```
=AVERAGE(INDEX(GoogleFinance("GOOG","all",WORKDAY(TODAY(),-200),TODAY()),,3))
```

But it is a function just to calculate Simple Moving Average. I researched more and found a script from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62242108/googlefinance-function-to-calculate-exponential-moving-average-in-google-sheets) that was supposed to be the solution:

​​​​

```
/**
 * Calculates the EMA of the range.
 *
 * @param {range} range The range of cells to calculate.
 * @param {number} n The number of trailing samples to give higer weight to, e.g. 30.
 * @return The EMA of the range.
 * @customfunction
 */
function EMA(range, n) {
  if (!range.reduce) {
    return range;
  }

  n = Math.min(n, range.length);
  var a = 2 / (n + 1);

  return range.reduce(function(accumulator, currentValue, index, array) {
    return currentValue != "" ? (currentValue * a + accumulator * (1-a)) : accumulator;
  }, 0);
}
```

But when I run it, it is no way near the actual value. Kindly can you guide me on how to calculate accurate EMA of stock after 200 days with a script or formula without iterating each previous day's value or as a next option can we calculate EMA from the Simple Moving Average of the last 200 days?

Here is the link to [Sample Data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_N8kDOrl15XF_Z-R4zK2GLzuKMAOERPYfQ4skfhehpw/edit#gid=685391261). In **Column U**, I am calculating EMA step by step, while **Column B** is the Simple Moving Average of 'GOOG' stock, can we get EMA using the data of **Column B** by creating some formula or script?

Comment: I'm not getting an error when I test this, it is just returning a number. In order to clarify this, please provide the error message you are getting, as well as the sample data you are working on.

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me, I have added sheet link and little explanation at the last of this question, you can see the data in this sheet,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue:

I think the referenced formula is not handling the first element in the series properly. The value of the EMA at time period 0 matches the value of the series itself. And since all the rest of the values depend on that one, the end result is wrong ([ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Exponential_moving_average)):

[image]

#### Solution:

Therefore, the `reduce` function should take the first value in the series as the initial value:

```
function EMA(range, n) {
  if (!range.reduce) {
    return range;
  }
  n = Math.min(n, range.length);
  const a = 2 / (n + 1);
  const first = range.shift();
  return range.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {
    return currentValue != "" ? (currentValue * a + accumulator * (1-a)) : accumulator;
  }, first);
}
```

[image]